# Input validation for cell phones and email on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

So I've been working on a custom online form and the `required` & `pattern` attributes don't seem to be supported by `IOS Safari` even though they say they do. What I'm trying to achieve is when the user tries to submit I want the input of the email and contact to be checked if they pass a certain format(like a regex for example) before submitting. Anybody know of a javascript/jquery solution to this?

Some sample code:

```
<h3>Email Address</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="emailAddress" name="email" placeholder="example@something.com" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h3>Contact Number(Cell Phone Preferred!)Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="number" name="phone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: Also, are those inputs inside a `<form>`? The `required` attribute only works if the input is inside a form element.

Comment: @Clonkex yes they are

Comment: @f.khantsis I edited my post

Comment: FYI for some reason while cleaning up your question @Shree added a space in the first `<h3>`, idk why he did that but if it were me I'd want to edit and remove it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery Validation Plugin to validate your field.You can use addMethod for pattern . For sample I use this on phone field.

[Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/)

```js
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true
    },
    phone: { required: true, regex : /^[\d\s]+$/, minlength: 5 }
  }
});
$.validator.addMethod(
"regex",
function(value, element, regexp) {
    var check = false;
    return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
},
"Please check your input."
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <h3>Email Address</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="emailAddress" name="email" placeholder="example@something.com" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Contact Number(Cell Phone Preferred!)Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="number" name="phone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

Comment: Can jquery rules be used to add a pattern as well? Using jquery validation plugins works on IOS safari for sure?

Comment: how would the syntax look if i wanted to include the pattern?

Comment: Glad to help :)